# Django formset - validate input based on user cookie?

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms, formsets

I have a Django form (TestForm) that contains a single field, quantity. I also have a Django formset (TestFormset) that contains multiple instances of my TestForm.

I want to write a custom clean() method for my TestFormset that validates that the sum of the quantities specified within my multiple TestForms is equal to a number, max_quantity, stored in a session variable.

I know that I am able to perform this validation within views.py (for example, after my formset is validated and cleaned, I could manually sum up the 'quantity' variables in my TestForms and check to ensure that they are equal to request.session['max_quantity'], throwing an error if any problems are found).

But ideally I'd love to move all my form validation logic into the clean() method of forms.py. However, I can't figure out how to pass an external value into my Formset that is not linked to one of its individual forms.

Is this possible to do?

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import BaseFormSet

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField()

class BaseTestFormset(BaseFormset):
    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):

            # Don't bother validating the formset unless each form is valid on its own

            return

        quantity = 0

        for form in self.forms:
            quantity += form.cleaned_data['quantity']

        # IF QUANTITY IS NOT EQUAL TO MAX_QUANTITY, THROW AN ERROR...
        # ...BUT HOW DO WE GET THE MAX_QUANTITY INTO THIS FUNCTION?
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import TestForm, BaseTestFormset

def serve_form(request):

    TestFormSet = formset_factory(TestForm, formset=BaseTestFormset)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TestFormSet(request.POST)

        # This method should check to ensure that the sum of quantities within our formsets does not exceed max_quantity
        if formset.is_valid():
              # Proceed to take action
    else:
        # Sample initial data
        formset = TestFormSet(initial=[{'quantity': 5}, {'quantity': 7}])

    # I CAN PASS MAX_QUANTITY INTO THE TEMPLATE... BUT HOW DO I GET IT INTO THE FORMSET VALIDATION METHOD?
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'formset': formset, 'max_quantity': request.session['max_quantity']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with forms, if you want access to something in a method you need to pass it in somewhere. You can do that in the initialiser if you like:

```
class BaseTestFormset(forms.BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.max_quantity = kwargs.pop('max_quantity', None)
        super(BaseTestFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        ...
        if quantity > self.max_quantity:
            ...
```

and in the view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = TestFormSet(request.POST, max_quantity=request.session['max_quantity'])
```

Comment: Of course! This makes so much sense. Thanks a million :)